# Deleting CloudFormation takes time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We are deploying using AWS SAM and the information in template.yaml is here.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
    template

    Sample SAM Template for template

Parameters:
    Prefix:
        Type: String
        Default: '__PREFIX__'
    DbSecretName:
        Type: String

Globals:
    Function:
        Runtime: nodejs18.x
        Timeout: 10
        MemorySize: 128

Resources:
    HelloWorldFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            FunctionName: !Sub '${Prefix}-hello-world'
            CodeUri: ../src/app
            Handler: app.lambdaHandler
            Architectures:
                - x86_64
            Environment:
                Variables:
                    DB_SECRET_NAME: !Ref DbSecretName
            Role: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn

        Metadata:
            BuildMethod: esbuild
            BuildProperties:
                Minify: true
                Target: 'es2022'
                Sourcemap: true
                EntryPoints:
                    - app.ts

    HelloWorldFunctionRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
            RoleName: !Sub '${Prefix}-hello-world-role'
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: '2012-10-17'
                Statement:
                    - Effect: Allow
                      Principal:
                          Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
                      Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Policies:
                - PolicyName: AllowSecretsManagerAccess
                  PolicyDocument:
                      Version: '2012-10-17'
                      Statement:
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
                            Resource: '*'
                            # Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:${DbSecretName}/*'
                - PolicyName: AllowEC2CreateNetworkInterface
                  PolicyDocument:
                      Version: '2012-10-17'
                      Statement:
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action: ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                            Resource: '*'
                - PolicyName: AllowEC2DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                  PolicyDocument:
                      Version: '2012-10-17'
                      Statement:
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action: ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                            Resource: '*'
                - PolicyName: AllowEC2DeleteNetworkInterface
                  PolicyDocument:
                      Version: '2012-10-17'
                      Statement:
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action: ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                            Resource: '*'
```

If I manually delete the stack after deploying this one, I will have to wait up to an hour with the status DELETE_IN_PROGRESS.

Is there any way to delete the stack quickly?

VPC was not involved, so I edited and reposted the question.

Newly created Stacks could be deleted.
The template.yaml was created with the same contents.

Stacks that took a long time to delete were those that had been created and deleted repeatedly.

I have not yet solved the problem, so if anyone has any insight, I would appreciate it.

Comment: This should not take that long. Does the deletion actually succeed in the end or does it fail?

Comment: Deletion will take place.
However, when I erase the VPC configuration and run it, it is still in DELETE_IN_PROGRESS state.
thankyou